# How Do I Export Part of a mySQL Table as XML in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

I've got a mySQL database and I want to export part of the db (not the whole thing) as XML.

In phpMyAdmin, how do I export XML from a table where "series=10", for example? If I click the export tab, and the choose XML as the export option, then the whole table will be exported as XML. I only want part of the database exported as XML.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the SQL tab. Craft a SQL statement that returns the 'part' of the db that you want exported. Then at the bottom of the page there is a 'Export' button. This will take you to a page that will allow you to export in various formats including XML.

Comment: Thank you vicTROLLA. That was easy. I just figured out that you can click the search tab, add your parameter, and then at the bottom click Export. Thanks for helping me.